# Refresh a Chatter Feed

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed

I came across an old article: [**How to refresh the chatter feed or feed item automatically?**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46830/how-to-refresh-the-chatter-feed-or-feed-item-automatically)

This seems like this is exactly what I'm looking for. Does anyone know if this code is still valid (I am running Classic)? Also, how (or where) do I enter the Javascript?

```
if (window.chatter) {
    var feed = chatter.getFeed();
    var feedConfig = feed.getConfig();
    feed.refresh({
        feedType : feedConfig.feedType,
        isFullRefresh : true,
        params : feedConfig
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you using lightning or classics?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal  I am running Classic