# autorefresh chatter feed from lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, chatter-feed

Can I autorefresh a chatter feed on a lightning record page when I an update is made on the record from an LWC also on that page? I've used [LMS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-message-service/documentation)(awesome btw) for LWC to LWC communication but haven't come across a way to autorefresh chatter without refreshing the entire page. If not possible, I'm just looking for confirmation so I can stop looking. . . :)

Comment: Does this solve your issue ? - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46830/how-to-refresh-the-chatter-feed-or-feed-item-automatically

Comment: Saw that one too. Didn’t work though